# Standing of all-in losers in a tournament

Tags: tournament, rules

When multiple players go all-in during a hand in a tournament, and lose, how is their relative standing (5th, 6th, etc.) determined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is determined by their stack size prior to the hand starting.

Comment: This is also true when playing multiple tables on the bubble in a hand-for-hand situation. So if there are two tables and player on each goes all in on the same hand, and they both bust, then the player with the shortest stack at the start of the hand is deemed to be the first person out of the two.

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk: so what happens in the hypothetical case where the players had the same stack size prior to the hand? : )

Comment: The universe implodes, I'm guessing.

Comment: If all players have the same amount of chips exactly on the bubble, they split the last prize according to the number of players with the same number of chips